# How to make a function use the value of .x instead of the string ".x" in the formula of the iterated glm function in R?

Tags: r

I do multiple glm using the walk function and would like to use individual models in the created list in cross-validation. The cv.glm function uses the formula from the glm object. Unfortunately, my code returns string ".x" instead of .x value (eg. 1), which prevents cv.glm from working. Can I force the value to be used instead of the string?

My code without cv.glm:

MODEL = NULL
MODELS.DF <- c(1:20)

```
walk(
  MODELS.DF,
  ~ {
    MODEL[[.x]] <<- glm(
      DataFrame$Event
      ~ ns(Temperature, df = .x),
      data = DataFrame,
      family = binomial,
      na.action = na.omit
    )
  }
)
```

If I use this code:

```
MODEL[[1]][["formula"]][[3]]
```

I get this result:

```
ns(Temperature, df = .x)
```

And I would like to get this:

```
ns(Temperature, df = 1)
```